# parameter limited dissolve doesn't remove vertices!

Tags: mesh, units

sorry just starting to use blender 2.8 
limited dissolve does not want to remove unnecessary vertices

[image]

Comment: Please specify the result you would like to see. For instance; highlighting the vertices you would like to have removed.

Comment: Judging by the number of selected vertices in the lower right corner, it seems you have duplicate vertices. Right click and choose Merge > By distance and try again